# Create another inline button in modeladmin edit form

Tags: ajax, silverstripe

I recently created product modeladmin as below, what i want is to show another inline button like 'Update URL'  next to category dropdown on change event, please see the url for preveiw.

http://minus.com/lj7czMhqI45TC

```
class Product extends DataObject
{

private static $db = array(
    'URLSegment' => 'Varchar(100)',
    'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'MetaTitle' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'MetaDescription' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'Content' => 'HTMLText',        
    "SortOrder" => "Int",       
    "Size" => "Text",
);


private static $defaults = array(
    'Title'=>'New Item',
    'URLSegment' => 'new-item'
);

private static $has_one = array(
    'ProductCategory' => 'ProductCategory',
    'Image1' => 'Image',
    'Image2' => 'Image',
    'Image3' => 'Image'
);

//The class of the page which will list this DataObject
//private static $listing_page_class = 'ProductCategory';
 //Class Naming (optional but reccomended)
private static $singular_name = "Product";
private static $plural_name = "Products";

private static $default_sort = '"Title" ASC';


static $summary_fields = array(
    "ProductThumbnail" => "Image",      
    "Title" => "Name",
    "Size" => "Size",
    'ProductCategory.Title' => 'Category'
);

/*
static $searchable_fields = array(
    'Title',
    'Size',
    'Content'=> array('title' => 'Content'),
    'ProductCategoryID' => array('title' => 'Product Category')
);
*/

static $field_labels = array(
    'Title' => 'Product Name' 
);


public function getCMSFields() 
{
     $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    / /$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Title','Name'));      

    //Remove Scafolded fields
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'URLSegment');
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'MetaTitle');
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'MetaDescription');


    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Title'));    

    if($this->ID)
     {
        $urlsegment = new SiteTreeURLSegmentField("URLSegment", $this->fieldLabel('URLSegment'));
        //$urlsegment->setURLPrefix($prefix);

        $helpText = _t('SiteTreeURLSegmentField.HelpChars', ' Special characters are automatically converted or removed.');
         $urlsegment->setHelpText($helpText);
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $urlsegment);
     }

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('Content'));    

     $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',new ToggleCompositeField('Metadata', 'Metadata',
        array(
            new TextField("MetaTitle", $this->fieldLabel('MetaTitle')),
            new TextareaField("MetaDescription", $this->fieldLabel('MetaDescription'))
        )
    ));



    $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","ProductCategoryID");


    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
         DropdownField::create('ProductCategoryID', _t("Product.CATEGORY", "Category"), $this->categoryoptions())
            ,
        ), 'Content');      


    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.ProductImages', $uploadField = new UploadField('Image1','Main Product Image'));
    $uploadField->setFolderName('Products/'.$this->URLSegment);
     $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.ProductImages', $uploadField = new UploadField('Image2','Second Product Image'));
    $uploadField->setFolderName('Products/'.$this->URLSegment);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.ProductImages', $uploadField = new UploadField('Image3','Third Product Image'));
    $uploadField->setFolderName('Products/'.$this->URLSegment);
    //$uploadField->setConfig('fileEditFields', 'priorityField');
    //$uploadField->FolderName = 'Uploads/'.'member-photos/'.($this->Title);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Size')); 


    $fields->removeFieldsFromTab('Root.Main', array('SortOrder'));

    return $fields;
}



public function getProductThumbnail() { 
    if ($Image = $this->Image1()->ID) { 
        return $this->Image1()->SetWidth(100); 
    } else { 
        return '(No Image)'; 
    } 
}   
/**
 * Helper function for generating list of categories to select from.
 * @return array categories
 */
private function categoryoptions() {
    $categories = ProductCategory::get()->map('ID', 'NestedTitle')->toArray();
    $categories = array(
        0 => _t("SiteTree.PARENTTYPE_ROOT", "Top-level page")
    ) + $categories;        

    return $categories;
}

}
```

Comment: what is the new inline button supposed to do? maybe it could be done in an onBeforeWrite/onAfterWrite hook instead?

Answer (score 2):

This code is based off the [cms/javascript/CMSMain.EditForm.js](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1/javascript/CMSMain.EditForm.js) code, which brings up the *Update URL* button, as well as many other things. The following code is written for Silverstripe 3.1.

We need to add add some javascript to the `Product` `DataObject`.

Create a `cms-product-page.js` file in the `mysite/javascript/` directory.

Load this javascript file in the `Product` `getCMSFields()` function:

**Product.php**

```php
class Product extends DataObject {

    ...

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        Requirements::javascript('mysite/javascript/cms-product-page.js');
        ...
    }

    ...
```

Here is the javascript to add a button after the category drop down:

**cms-product-page.js**

```js
(function($) {
    $.entwine('ss', function($){

        // This binds the following to your Category select box
        $('.cms-edit-form select[name=ProductCategoryID]').entwine({
            // Constructor: onmatch
            onmatch : function() {
                var self = this;

                // This calls the function to create and hide the new button
                self._addActions();

                // This is the event listener, which will display the button when this field is changed
                this.bind('change', function(e) {
                    $('.customButton', self.parent()).show();
                });

                this._super();
            },
            onunmatch: function() {
                this._super();
            },

            // This is the function that creates and hides the button
            _addActions: function() {
                var self = this;
                var button;

                // update button
                button = $('<button />', {
                    'class': 'customButton ss-ui-button-small',
                    'text': 'Button text',
                    'click': function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        self.buttonActionFuction(self.val());
                    }
                });

                // insert elements
                self.parent().append(button);
                button.hide();
            }, 

            // This is the function that is called when the button is pressed
            buttonActionFuction: function(title) {
                var button = $('.customButton', this.parent());
                button.hide();
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Currently the button will appear when the category is changed, and will disappear when the button is pressed. More javascript will need to be added for the button to do something useful.

Comment: Thanks 3dgoo, for clear instructions, this is great help for me. Though I found CMSMain.EditForm.js earlier, but did not understand them. Thanks alot